# How to manually add SSZipArchive to my project

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, ssziparchive

First off, I'm a Mac OSX newbie, both using and programming, but it's been thrust upon me. My project is moving along nicely, but I need to unzip a file, and it looks like SSZipArchive seems like the way to go. I want to manually add it to my project, so that it stays all together in my source code control system. Others, esp. the release engineer, shouldn't need to do anything, and we need to have all the source code local.

I've tried a million ways and back, only to keep getting the dreaded "No Such module" error. I've researched for a couple days now, and still no closer. So I'm starting from scratch in a new project to say what I'm doing and to plead for some help here. All this is being done on an El Capitan laptop, using Xcode 7.3.1, with Swift 2.2.

1. Create a Cocoa Application project, calling it 'ziptest', using Swift, nothing else checked. Build it just for fun.
2. Drag 'n' Drop the SSZipArchive folder found in the master.zip downloaded from the SSZipArchive GitHub site into my project. I'm not sure where it should go, or if it matters - top level, between ziptest project icon and the ziptest group or inside the ziptest group. But I'll put it inside the ziptest group. Now I'm faced with a new question - for the "Added folders", do I want to "Create groups" or "Create folder references". I do copy the items, because, as I said, I want to add them to SCCS later. I saw somewhere here on Stackexchange to make sure it is Group, so that's what I'll do. Build again and it still works.
3. I know I need a "bridging header" file, so I'll create it. I thought at some point, Xcode asked if I wanted to create it, but the above step doesn't do that. After much experimention, I found that if I d'n'd the SSZipArchive.m/.h files directly, it asks me. It doesn't put anything into it, but at least it creates it and updates the Build Settings. But I do this now manually by right clicking on the ziptest group folder, select New File... and create an empty Header File called "ziptest-Bridging-Header.h", following the pattern from the Xcode created one, being sure to check off the ziptest Target.
4. I add:

`#import "SSZipArchive.h"`

to that file. And building still works.

5. I added ziptest-Bridging-Header.h as the Objective-C Bridging Header in the Build Settings. And building still works.
6. Now comes the moment of truth. I add:

`#import SSZipArchive`

to AppDelegate.swift and I get the dreaded `No such module 'SSZipArchive'`

What am I doing wrong?

**Edited to add:** Oh, I also added libz.dylib to the Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries part. Doesn't help, of course, because we haven't even gotten to the link phase yet.

Comment: Xcode 8 is released recently. If you upgrade to Swift 3 you could use the built-in Swift Package Manager to make this kind of work easier.

Comment: Well, like I said, I don't really want to use a package, because I want to be able to deliver all the source code. Unless the Package Manager actually copies the code to the project.

Comment: Did you add it to the Target's "Embedded Binaries"?

Comment: BTW, I'm not familiar with SPM yet but with similar systems, "add manually (i.e., not use a package)" and "deliver source code" are completely orthogonal.

Comment: I don't understand that comment. I want to manually add the source code for SSZipArchive, because I want to add the source code for my entire project into the SCCS. I don't want it dependent on running something else like SPM at release compile time to get 3rd party source code, because then I don't have control over which version is used.